# Combinations of a list in google biquery-sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to find the all unique possible combination of values in a column in a table. For example, for column values 1,2,3,4,5. i want the result to be [1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5] but dont want to include [2,1],[3,1] etc. Since [1,2] & [2,1] are similar/same

Will appreciate any pointers to construct the query to find the combination of the values.

thanks

Comment: are you referring that you need the combinations of 2 without permutations of the elements in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`:

```
select t1.col, t2.col
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.col < t2.col;
```

If there can be duplicate values in the column, use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct t1.col, t2.col
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.col < t2.col;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following code to generate it in BQ:

```
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1 , 5, 1)) AS list)

, table2 AS (
  SELECT 
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1 , 5, 1)) AS list)

SELECT DISTINCT
  table1.list number1,
  table2.list number2
FROM 
  table1
  JOIN table2
    ON table2.list <= table1.list
ORDER BY
  number1, number2
```

This concept is almost the same as the one proposed by Gordon Linoff, the only difference is the <= operator instead of <. If we join only based on < operator we won't obtain all the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach avoiding self-joining

```
select distinct value, value2
from (
  select *, array_agg(value) over(order by value rows between 1 following and unbounded following) values
  from data   
), unnest(values) value2
```